# Free $R$-module $G$ with countably infinite basis isomorphic to direct sum of $G$ with $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

> Let $G$ be a free $R$-module on a countably infinite set. How can I show that $G \cong G \oplus G$.

This is clearly false for finite sets, so how does the fact that it's countably infinite make it true?

Comment: An infinite set can be put in bijection with its product with itself.  Since we're talking about free modules, such a bijection on the generators will extend to an isomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that if $A$ is an infinite set, then $A\cong A\sqcup A$ (disjoint union).

The remaining ingredient you then need is that free modules of the same rank (ie, free modules on sets of the same cardinality) are isomorphic, and that if $M$ is free on the set $X$ and $N$ is free on the set $Y$ then $M\oplus N$ is free on $X\sqcup Y$.